# fetching data from a site using jsoup

Tags: java, html, xml-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to fetch data from a site using the following code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {       
    Document d=Jsoup.connect("some site URL")
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 3912.101.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36").timeout(100000).get();
    Elements e = d.select("span[class=lrg bold]");
    for (Element element : e) {
      System.out.println("aaaaaaaa"+element.text());
    }
  }
}
```

This way i want to get price information from a site. but the problem is Price for one product has two rules. sometimes price available in `<del class="grey">` or else price is available is `<span class="bld lrg red">`. If the price is available in both rules i want to take just the first one. If the first one is not available then i want the price value from second one. how can i give condition in element.

Comment: Why don't you just to two selects and apply the condition yourself?

Comment: i cannot do that as i am not just fetching the data from that one. i am using lots of rules from different sites and pages. so i have everything in order and i cannot change the order or add extra rule in one case.. i am reading rules from XML file as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put your required locig into one css selector. However, it should be very easy to accomplish what you need like this:

```
Elements e = d.select("del.grey");
if (e.size() == 0){
    e = d.select("span.lrg.bold");
}

//do stuff with e
```

Note, that I changed the selectors to use proper class name syntax.

Comment: see what i wanted is an automated program which can crawl the data from the sites if we will set the rules in xml file . in this case we have to change the code while using a different site. i have to get name, price, description, url, image from each page and these all arranged in order in as xml file. in Price field i felt some difficulty

Comment: if both were span classes i used this span[class~=(?i)(bld lrg red|price bld)] but this case one is span class and another one is del so i cannot use this way